# Can I use Firestore with firebase sdk and cloud function at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Sorry, there is no code in my question, it's about seeking suggestions.

Currently, I am using cloud function to use Firestore as a database. Again I also need real-time synchronization for some feature in my react-app.
For security purposes, I change all read and write in Firestore security rules to **false**.

So, can I use Firestore for direct connection in my react-app with cloud function at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No.  If your security rules don't allow any read access, then web and mobile client will not be able to read anything.